# SyntaxError "unexpected character after line continuation character" when trying to create exe using PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I want to create a .exe file out of a simple python file. My test file is called test.py and contains only one line of code:

```
print("test successful")
```

Using Anaconda Prompt, I start Python by typing "python". Then I type the following and expect it to work:

```
C:\Users\sean\Anaconda3\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed C:\Users\sean\documents\test.py
```

But I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character in python
```

Everything I've written is plain text, so I don't know what else to try. Is Anaconda Prompt the right place to try this? Just a thought...

Comment: Did you transfer this from a mac? As in the script

Comment: No, I created everything today using Windows 10.

Comment: Can you post ur code pls

Comment: This is it. One line: print("test successful")

Comment: Thats odd, ill have to research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this from your shell, not inside the python IDE. Try the same command but without first entering the IDE (i.e. do not run `python` first)